# Where is the application pool meta data stored for IIS 6

Tags: iis-6, application-pool

In IIS 6 (Windows Server 2003R2), where is the metadata stored, particularly for application pools? I am experiencing some unexpected behavior when switching between two seemingly identical app pools (at least as far at the GUI displays), and would like to check the raw data to see if something is corrupt or incorrect.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is aimed at [webmasters](http://webamsters.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the IIS6 configuration is stored at C:\Windows\system32\inetserv\metabase.xml file and not in the users home directory.

Comment: maybe just a typo, but in my environment, it is in `inetsrv`, not `inetserv`. in any case, this got me what i needed, thank you!